# Wrong styling of p:dataTable with f:facet name="header"

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am showing data in a `<p:dataTable>`, but it shows like this

[image]

The view markup is straightforward:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="campaignSummaryTable" var="mout" value="#{campaignSummarySearchRes.summaryList}" height="500" scrollable="true"  >
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Campaign Code"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.shortCode}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Message"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.message}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Option 1"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.option1}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Option 2"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.option2}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Option 3"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.option3}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Option 4"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.option4}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Other"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.other}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>                  
</h:form>
```

How I can solve this issue? The header and the content should have the same column width.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `style="width:125px"` attribute to your columns so they look like this one:

```
    <p:column headerText="Campaign Code" style="width:125px">
            <h:outputText value="#{mout.shortCode}" />
    </p:column>
```

I also put the header as an attribute of column. I dont know if thats neccessary, but it looks better.

[See also PF Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf)

Answer (score 0):

What version do you use?

You do not have to put a `facet` in a column; each column has a `headerText` attribute. Look at this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableComplex.jsf.